# Maximal interval of existence of solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-calculus

Let $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a matrix that has exactly one real eigenvalue, the $-1$. Find the maximal interval of existence of solution $X:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ of $$X'(t)=X^2(t) \\ X(0)=A$$

That $-1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ we have that there is a vector $v$ such that $-A=-v$, right?

If we consider the problem in an interval of the form $(-a,a)$ then we know that there is a solution, or not? So we have to expand this interval as possible, or what do we have to do to find the maximal interval?

Comment: Check again the eigenvalue equation. // As there is only one matrix, everything commutes and you can solve this similar to the scalar case

Comment: Ah the eigenvalue equation should be $Av=-v$, right? @LutzLehmann

Comment: So do we have to find a solution of the problem first? @LutzLehmann

Comment: Yes. And in that direction the equation reduces directly to its scalar variant. But to justify that you need to incorporate that $A$ is the only matrix, so all solution expressions will be analytical matrix functions of $A$. Finding the solution first will reduce the effort greatly.

Comment: So we solve $x'(t)=x^2(t)$ and we get $x(t)=-\frac{1}{c+t}$. Using $x(0)=A$ we get $c=-\frac{1}{A}$, right? @LutzLehmann